# How to pass parameters in scoring attributes of sklearn cross_validate function?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to change the average parameter of the precision metric because this error occurs

> "ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose
>   another average setting."

I have read the official website but I couldn't find an answer in terms of using cross_validate function.

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
scoring = ['accuracy', 'precision']

scores = cross_validate(clf, X, Y, scoring=scoring, cv=10, return_train_score=False, n_jobs=-1)
```

Any idea how to handle this?

Answer (score 8):

Use `make_scorer` which allows you to specify parameters for your individual scoring metrics, then use a dictionary to map multiple metrics to names:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, make_scorer
scoring = {'Accuracy': make_scorer(accuracy_score), 
           'Precision': make_scorer(precision_score, average='None')}

scores = cross_validate(clf, X, Y, scoring=scoring, ...)
```

Refer [this](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_multi_metric_evaluation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-multi-metric-evaluation-py) example